# Have no idea how to fix illegal start of expression and .class errors JAVA

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm completely new to java coding and I am learning to call methods.
I'm running into a few problems with my code that takes a random array after user input and finds all numbers divisible by six.
https://ideone.com/ZvmTTk

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CS
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arrayLen;
        int[] numbers;

        System.out.println("Please input the length of the array above 99.");
        while (true)
        {
            if (user_input.hasNextint())
            {
                arrayLen = user_input.nextInt();
                if (arrayLen >= 100)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Value entered less than 99. Please enter another integer.");

                }
                if (user_input = string)
                {
                    System.out.println("Input was not an integer. Please enter an integer above 99.");
                    user_input.next();
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Input was not an integer. Please enter an integer above 99.");
                    user_input.next();
                }
            }
            numbers = FillArray(arrayLen);

            System.out.printf("-Your Array-");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++);
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print(numbers[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("---" + numbers[1]);
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("\n You chose an array length of %d\n You had %d numbers that could be divided by six\n", arrayLength, FindMod6(numbers));
        }
        public static; int;[]; FillArray(int length);
        {

            int[] temp = new int[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                temp[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

                return temp;
            }

            public static; int Finddivision;(int[] array);
            {

                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    if (array[1] % 6 == 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                return count;
            }
}
```

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code. Please scrap it and start from the beginning, after having spent some time with basic Java tutorials.

Comment: Yes. get one little bit of code working, then build on it. If you break it, go back to the last running version.

Comment: It's not really good to have `while(true)` and using a `break` to escape from that. A good practice is to find out in which condition you want the program to end and set the loop conditional to be that. But yeah, if you're simply learning to call methods, I would definitely start somewhere easier and work your way up.

Comment: You should edit your question to address a specific problem and please provide the error output you are receiving.

Comment: I dare say that quite a few mistakes would have been obvious if you had formatted and indented your code correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I'll describe all syntax errors from top to bottom. I won't elaborate on the semantic errors here because there are simply far too many.

> Line 13: `if(user_input.hasNextint())`

The class `java.util.Scanner` does not have a method called `hasNextint()`. Methods in Java are case sensitive (as in pretty much every other programming language), so you'll need to write `hasNextInt()` instead.

> Line 25-35: `if(user_input = string) ...`

There's so much wrong with this if-else-statement - both syntactically and semantically - that I won't elaborate on this. To be honest, you can just remove that one.

> Line 42: `if(i%5 == 0)`

The variable `i` is only defined inside the for-loop directly above this code block. Remove the semicolon `;` behind the for-loop.

> Line 52: `..., arrayLength, FindMod6(numbers));`

There's no method named `FindMod6` which takes an `int[]` as parameter.

> Line 54: `public static; int;[]; FillArray(int length);`

You're missing a closing brace `}` to end the main method here.

If you wanted to define a new method which is `public static`, returns an `int[]` and takes one `int` parameter, replace the quoted part with

```
public static int[] FillArray(int length)
```

Semicolons `;` have nothing to do in a method definition.

> Line 65: `public static; int Finddivision;(int[] array);`

You're missing a closing brace `}` to end your `FillArray` method here. As well as that, your method **has to** return something before ending.

Same issue as above, semicolons `;` have nothing to do in a method definition. Use

```
public static int Finddivision(int[] array)
```

---

**Conclusion:** Read Oracle's [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) and use an IDE that supports syntax and error highlighting as well as a code assistant, for example [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/), [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/idea.jsp) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/).